# Paste to a particular line in vim without moving the cursor

Tags: vim

Lets say the cursor is at line N and we yank it with yy and we want to paste to 20 lines below the cursor is. Is it possible to do so without moving the cursor down like 20j, p, 20k? Tried 20p but it just pasted 20 duplicate lines. I can't find a solution after some googling, and I can't be the only one that need this.

What I want to do is yank (yy) the current line, paste to 20 lines below, go down one line (j), yank (yy) the current line, paste to 33 lines below, go down one line (j), yank (yy) the current line, paste to 41 lines below, go down one line (j), rinse and repeat

Comment: the `20` you have to type anyway, and `p` too, so you are just fighting with one single keystroke? `20jp` is fine, isn't it? if you want to go back to the line you yanked, just press `\`\``

Comment: `` is better than 20k but I was hoping there is something better

Comment: do you really need a mapping? say press for example `20<someKey>` then vim does paste without cursor  moving?

Comment: @Kent If the only way to achieve this is to create a custom mapping, I will accept your `` if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't believe that this question has been here for 5 years and nobody has actually given the right answer...

What you're looking for is the ex command `:put` (https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput).

From the documentation:

```
:[line]pu[t] [x]
Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default current line).
```

So with your example, the steps would be:

```
yy
:+20put
```

Also see this reddit post, I found it quite helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/p7blsn/question_how_to_paste_register_to_a_specific_line/

Comment: Thanks for providing the right answer to my 5-year-old question!

Comment: No problem, I actually came across this question because the reddit post above linked to it. I noticed that nobody had actually answered it and figured it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `:co[py]` command:

```
:[range]co[py] {address}                   :co :copy
     Copy the lines given by [range] to below the line
     given by {address}.
```

So for the example given: `:co .+20` would copy the current line 20 lines down.

Comment: I wanted to yank one line and copy at 20 lines down. Not the entire 20 lines.

Comment: If you don't specify a range the default is the current line. So this will copy the current line and insert it 20 lines down in the file.

Comment: I tried `:co +20` but the cursor went down with the copy, so I still had to do \`\`. Compare it to the conventional `yy 20j p` \`\`, there's only one less key to press so the gains isn't really significant. But thanks for sharing this, it's always good to learn something new.

Comment: Apologies, you're right. I retested and found that the cursor indeed moves.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a built-in command/option for `pP`, there is no one. You can always press `` to go back your old position.

If you want to create custom mapping,  there are many ways. E.g. write a function, write a custom command etc.

If you just want to automate some actions, like, for each line between 2-20, duplicate and copy to 5 lines below current line. you can consider to use `:g` command.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to copy line 20 and paste it into line 40, then do

```
:20t40
```

If you want to copy from line 20 to 25 and paste it into line 40 then do

```
:20,25t40
```